# CollapsiblePanelExtender does not work with CollapsedSize="0"

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, collapsiblepanelextender

This "CollapsiblePanelExtender" works ok only if I use CollapsedSize="1".
When using CollapsedSize="0" it collapses but does not show when clicked...
Any ideas ?

```
        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender 
            ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" 
            runat="server" 
                TargetControlID="pBody"         
                CollapseControlID="pHeader" 
                ExpandControlID="pHeader"   
                Collapsed="false" 
                TextLabelID="lblText" 
                CollapsedText="Click to Show Content..." 
                ExpandedText="Click to Hide Content..." 
                CollapsedSize="1"
                AutoCollapse="False"
                AutoExpand="False"
                ScrollContents="True"
                ExpandDirection="Vertical"
                SuppressPostBack="true" >
        </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Comment: Do you know if it is browser related? Have you tried it in multiple browsers?